# prevent adding child component size to parent component size in wpSelectComponents

Tags: inno-setup

I've a component (SQL server LocalDB) and a child component (VC++ 2015-2022), both with specific `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired`.
The problem is the child component's size is added to parent component's size when selected one of the pair.
With this small size difference, I will simply define `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` for the parent component with higher value and 0 for the child.
The question is, how can I prevent this size addition.
[image]

Total space required is right with 1x parent's size and 1x child size (tested with extreme high child's `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired`).

Comment: You keep asking new and new questions and you so far didn't [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a single answer you were give here.